# Eloquent Return Non Associative Array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get an array list of IDs to pass onto another model query.

```
$companies = $user->companies->pluck('id');
```

But it keeps returning an associative array as such:

```
[ 0 => 2, 1 => 9]
```

So when I pass it to the find method on my Company model, like this

```
$company = Company::find($companies);
```

I get the following error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I need to be able to pass a non-associative array to the call like such:

```
Company::find([2,9]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in Laravels source code

[src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L79)

```
public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    if (is_array($id)) {
        return $this->findMany($id, $columns);
    }
    $this->query->where($this->model->getQualifiedKeyName(), '=', $id);
    return $this->first($columns);
}
```

`find()` will internally call `findMany()` if the first parameter is an array. But `$user->companies->pluck('id')` returns a `Collection` and the `Builder` creates a wrong query. So your options are:

Use `findMany()`:

```
$company = Company::findMany($companies);
```

Convert the Collection to an array:

```
$company = Company::find($companies->toArray());
```

Use `whereIn()`:

```
$company = Company::whereIn('id', $companies)->get();
```

But actually that all doesn't seem to make any sense, because `$user->companies` probably already contains the collection you want to fetch from DB. So you could also write:

```
$company = $user->companies;
```

However - the fact that you are using singular naming (company) for a set of companies, let me think that you are trying to achieve something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

Try that:

```
$companies = $user->companies->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Just did a test in tinker and the result is a flat array, the "find" will work for sure!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the whereIn method

`Company::whereIn('id', $companies)->get();`